# Markdown table overflowing in rendered PDF

Tags: tables, pdftex, markdown, page, overflow

I have a markdown file with many pipetables. It is linked in a tex file.

In most of them the text is too long for one row. When i create the pdf with `pdflatex --shell-escape ./test.tex` I would assume that there would be some automatic line breaking when the text is too long for the page, but that is not the case. The table is overflowing the page border and parts are not visible any more.

This is a little example which demonstrates the problem:

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\def\markdownOptionPipeTables{true}

\begin{document}

\markdownInput{test.md}

\end{document}
```

**test.md**

```
# Test table 

|||Euro|
|:---|:---|---:|
| 1. | This is a very long line that should not overflow the page borders. But it does. I didn't found a solution to get a line break done.  | 10,00 Euro |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/issues/113#issuecomment-1002814678, the author of the `markdown` package provides a solution to your problem.
He defines a custom table renderer which uses the `tabularx` environment.

Adapted to your specific example, you could use the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{markdown}

\markdownSetup{pipeTables = true}

\makeatletter
\newcount\markdownLaTeXRowCounter
\newcount\markdownLaTeXRowTotal
\newcount\markdownLaTeXColumnCounter
\newcount\markdownLaTeXColumnTotal
\newtoks\markdownLaTeXTable
\newtoks\markdownLaTeXTableAlignment
\newtoks\markdownLaTeXTableEnd

\markdownSetup{
  renderers = {
    table = {%
      \markdownLaTeXTable={}%
      \markdownLaTeXTableAlignment={}%
      \markdownLaTeXTableEnd={%
        \end{tabularx}%
      }%
      \ifx\empty#1\empty\else
        \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{%
          \begin{table}
          \caption{#1}
          \centering
        }%
        \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTableEnd{%
          \end{table}%
        }%
      \fi
      \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}%
      }%
      \markdownLaTeXRowCounter=0%
      \markdownLaTeXRowTotal=#2%
      \markdownLaTeXColumnTotal=#3%
      \markdownLaTeXRenderTableRow
    }
  }
}

\def\markdownLaTeXRenderTableRow#1{%
  \markdownLaTeXColumnCounter=0%
  \ifnum\markdownLaTeXRowCounter=0\relax
    \markdownLaTeXReadAlignments#1%
    \markdownLaTeXTable=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\the\expandafter\markdownLaTeXTable\expandafter{%
        \the\markdownLaTeXTableAlignment
      }%
    }%
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{\hline}%
  \else
    \markdownLaTeXRenderTableCell#1%
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{\hline}%
  \fi
  \advance\markdownLaTeXRowCounter by 1\relax
  \ifnum\markdownLaTeXRowCounter>\markdownLaTeXRowTotal\relax
    \expandafter\the\expandafter\markdownLaTeXTable
    \the\markdownLaTeXTableEnd
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi\markdownLaTeXRenderTableRow
}

\def\markdownLaTeXReadAlignments#1{%
  \advance\markdownLaTeXColumnCounter by 1\relax
  \if#1d%
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTableAlignment{|X<{\RaggedRight}}%
  \else
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTableAlignment{|#1<{\RaggedRight}}%
  \fi
  \ifnum\markdownLaTeXColumnCounter<\markdownLaTeXColumnTotal
    \relax
  \else
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTableAlignment{|}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi\markdownLaTeXReadAlignments
}

\def\markdownLaTeXRenderTableCell#1{%
  \advance\markdownLaTeXColumnCounter by 1\relax
  \ifnum\markdownLaTeXColumnCounter<\markdownLaTeXColumnTotal\relax
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{#1&}%
  \else
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{#1\\}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi\markdownLaTeXRenderTableCell
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
# Test table 

|||Euro|
|:---|---|---:|
| 1. | This is a very long line that should not overflow the page borders. But it does. I didn't found a solution to get a line break done.  | 10,00 Euro |
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the second column is no longer left-aligned (`---` vs. `:---` in your original example).

[image]